# Laravel filter max date on intermediate pivot table

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a relationship many to many (between Invoice and Shift) as defined

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Invoice extends Model
{
    public $primaryKey = 'id';
    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id',
        'date_ins',
        'tas',
    ];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(User::class,'id','user_id');
    }

    /**
     * The roles that belong to the invoice.
     */
    public function shifts()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Shift::class, 'invoice_shift')
        ->withPivot(['invoice_id','shift_id', 'shift_taken_id', 'shift_swapped_date','shift_taken_date', 'tas','msg','status_tas']);
    }

}
```

Then Shift model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Shift extends Model
{
    public $primaryKey = 'id';
    protected $fillable = [
        'code',
        'description',
    ];
    /**
     * The users that belong to the role.
     */
    public function invoices()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Invoice::class, 'invoice_shift');
    }
}
```

in the pivot table i have also a column called shift_swapped_date,
I wanted just to retrieve for all invoices the one row that has max value of this date in pivot table.
I tried in the controller

```
$invoices = Invoice::with('shifts')
->get();   
$invoices->max('pivot.shift_swapped_date');
```

but it doesn't work
I cannot figure out how to do it...
Thx

Answer (score 0):

If that is not working try to run below solution:

```
$invoices = Invoice::with(['shifts' => function($query) {

    $query->max('shift_swapped_date');

}])->get();
```

Comment: doesn't work; field "shift_swapped_date" is in pivot table invoice_shift .

Comment: if i output sql with ->toSql() it retrieves to me just  "select * from `invoices`"

Comment: it should be with some joins at least no?

Comment: `dd($query);` add this inside the closure function it should output the pivot table.

Comment: yes, join can be the last option but the relations should work.

Comment: it doesn't show the query but the list of arrays and attributes mmm nested....i cannot find any max :(

Comment: it should generate a groupby by invoice_id but doesnt work ...

Comment: it generate select min(`invoice_shift`.`shift_swapped_date`) as aggregate from `shifts` inner join `invoice_shift` on `shifts`.`id` = `invoice_shift`.`shift_id` where `invoice_shift`.`invoice_id` in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5) and this not correct